# Python Prime Sum Programme

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, math

I am trying to use python to solve Project Euler's questions.

The question i met is to add to all prime number below 2 millions.

My codes:

```
import math

def isPrime(number):
if number == 2:
    return True
for x in range(2,number):
    if number % x ==0:
        return False
return True

number = 3
ans = 2 
while number<=2000000:
    if(isPrime(number)):
       print(number)
       ans+=number
    number+=2
```

I think it is working, however it is processing too slow.
Is there any way to enhance it? (Without using a prime number set in memory). Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try `for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number))+1):` ?

Comment: thx to Pham Trung. The keyword is "Sieve of Erastothenes"

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_prime(number):
  if number == 2:
    return True
  for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1):
    if number%x == 0:
      return False
  return True
```

If you ensure there's no number till square root of given number which can divide the given number, then you can mark it *prime*. No need to check till `number - 1`. Although a small improvement, could be significant in your case.

Comment: No small improvement! n vs sqrt(n) is a significant complexity reduction.

Answer (score 0):

Run your loop up to the square root of the number. This will reduce the complexity.